# Push a directory to $PATH on Unix to call binaries without prefix

Tags: linux, unix, directory

Let´s say I´m in a directory in `~/Code/proj` and there is a binary called `proj` that I compiled via GCC and the way I can run this program is:

```
~/Code/proj $ ./proj
```

How do I push the proj directory to `$PATH` so from now on all binaries in this directory can be called without the `./` prefix?

Comment: Which platform are you using?

Comment: @crazy_prog: the tags mention Linux.

Comment: There is security issue putting current directory in the path. let say, you are in `/tmp` where everybody can drop anything. and you execute `ls`, it is possible that somebody have dropped malicious `ls` executable there and instead of what you've expected, ls will do something else. Of course that depends on the order in your path, but generally in snot good idea

Comment: Yes, and generally it is better, if having `.` in your `PATH` is required (and you should avoid that), to put it at the end of the `PATH`

Comment: Hey, you can just add the _current directory_ to the path instead of `.`, as my solution demonstrates!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`export PATH="$PATH:$(pwd)"`

ie, append your current directory (NOT `.`!) to `PATH`.

Comment: what is the `-P` do, my version of bash doesn't honor the -P. Good luck to all.

Comment: It means to resolve all symlinks for the path. This is really curious that your pwd version does not support that! I have been using this option for at least three years.

Comment: yes, actually, it bombs out my terminal session and closes it ;-) Thanks for sharing, would be good to use if it is available.

Comment: OK, removed it from the solution. Don't forget to accept the answer if it suits you ;)

Comment: `export PATH="$PATH:$PWD"` - shorter, faster, and works in every shell that provides the PWD variable (includes the posixy dash).

Answer (score 0):

Pushing a directory into `PATH` don't means much.

To know what your `PATH` is just type

```
echo $PATH
```

You could change your `PATH` or put your binary in some directory inside it.

You can temporarily change your `PATH` with a command like suggested [by fge](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8546027/841108)

If your login shell is `bash` which is often the case, you could edit one of the `$HOME/.bashrc` or `$HOME/.profile` files to set your path. (For `zsh` shell the start-up files are different, and you may need to run `rehash` after changing things related to your path).

Many Linux distributions give you a `PATH` containing your `$HOME/bin/`; then you could create that directory (if relevant) and copy your executable inside it.

I find that having few directories in the `PATH` is cleaner. I prefer copying my executables and scripts in one single directory like `$HOME/bin/`